# ord(os.urandom(x)) clarification - string, character

Tags: python, ord

The following is a function that my professor made, and we are to use this function in our code:

```
    import os
    def rando_num(num_bytes):
        return ord(os.urandom(num_bytes))
```

Instructions say to make a create_list function, call rando_num within create_list, and to do some checks on the return. I keep getting errors, and out of curiosity I tested rando_num by itself and got the same errors.

If I call 
    rando_num('5')
I get "'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

If I call
    rando_num(5)
I get "ord() expected a character, but string of length 5 found"

If I try 
    rando_num('a') I get "'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

I read up on os.urandom and ord, so I'm confused about what I need to put in the function. I thought urandom returns a string, but then the error says ord expects a character. I can't alter the professor's code, so how in the world do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

As [Python's documentation for os.urandom](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.urandom) says, `urandom` returns "a string of n random bytes." And as [Python's documentation for ord](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#ord) says, `ord` must be "given a string representing one Unicode character."

The only way I can see to reconcile those two without modifying your professor's code is to have `urandom` return only *one* byte which Python interprets as a string with one Unicode character. That character will be limited to have the `ord` result of `0` through `255`, but it will work.

So set up your code to always call `rando_num` with an argument of `1`. Calling that repeatedly in effect gives a sequence of random numbers between `0` and `255`, but done by the operating system rather than by the programming language (which is want `random` does). This does work in my Python 3.7.